# Bone hide_viewport keyframe not showing in Action Editor

Tags: animation, armature, bones, keyframes, actions

I have an Action like this:

> frame 0: Bone visible
>
> frame 1: Bone hidden
>
> frame 2: Bone visible

[image]

I hide the bone by animating the `hide_viewport` (TV icon):
[image]

but as you can clearly see the keyframes are not showing in the action editor:
[image]

So how exactly do I view/edit them?

Answer (score 0):

They are in the different animation block, open the Dope Sheet:

[image]

Comment: so I can't have multiple hide bone animations?